# Problem with a JavaScript animation applied to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<body onload="load_script()">
<h3 id="description">Text</h3>

<script>
var size_start_h3 = 10.72;
var size_end_h3 = 18.72;

function start_h3() {
 if(size_start_h3 < size_end_h3) {
    document.getElementById("description").style.fontSize = size_start_h3;
    size_start_h3 += 2;
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    start_h3();
    }, 1200);
 }
}       

function load_script() {
   start_h3();
   // others functions;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a JavaScript code; it works if I'm offline; if I'm online, it doesn't work when I include it in a .js file and even if I insert it into the  tag

I set two variables the size that the title h3 will take at the beginning and at the end.
I have written a function based on which if the initial dimension is less than the final one, the text will gradually increase its size of 2 px at a time until it reaches the final size.
The startup function will be started via another function when the page is loaded (along with other script functions)

Nevertheless, the console doesn't return me errors and if I write console.log(size_start_h3) at the end of the function its value changes up to 18.72; so, function work but the size of h3 doesn't change.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CSS measures require identification of the measure as part of the unit value. You need to append that to your string for the font size.

Here I added "px":

```html
<html>
<body onload="load_script()">
<h3 id="description">Text</h3>

<script>
var size_start_h3 = 10.72;
var size_end_h3 = 18.72;

function start_h3() {
 if(size_start_h3 < size_end_h3) {
    document.getElementById("description").style.fontSize = size_start_h3 + "px";
    size_start_h3 += 2;
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    start_h3();
    }, 1200);
 }
}       

function load_script() {
   start_h3();
   // others functions;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. You are absolutely right. Now works.
But, my curiosity is why it works offline?
This is the first time I write on this portal, what to say? Really useful.
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's an interesting question that I cannot answer. There are too many variables in the idea of "when I'm off line" that I don't have insight into. Suffice it to say your code was in error and going to a staging environment exposed that. Thats good. Glad to help. Perhaps you can mark my answer as accepted when you some rep.

Comment: For "offline" I mean I'm working locally, so the various .html .css .js files are not yet loaded on the hosting server.